# Oracle - Update statement in Stored Procedure does not work once in a while

Tags: oracle

We have a stored procedure that inserts data into a table from some temporary tables in oracle database. There is an update statement after the insert that updates a flag in the same table based on certain checks. At the end of the stored procedure commit happens. 
The problem is that the update works on 95% cases but in some cases it fails to update. When we try to run it again without changing anything, it works. Even trying to execute the same stored procedure on the same data at some other time, works perfectly. I haven't found any issues in the logic in the stored procedure. I feel there is some database level issue which we are not able to find (maybe related to concurrency). Any ideas on this would be very helpful.

Comment: Concurrency in a database is two edged sword. As Chris has pointed out, adding an exception to the procedure that logs the error would certainly help. When developing for a multi-user environment there are a few things that you need to take care of. The [Lost Update](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2005/08/something-different-part-i-of-iii.html) problem could be what you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the source code we will just be guessing. The most obvious suggestion that I can think of is that it hits an exception somewhere along the way in some cases and never gets as far as the commit. Another possibility is that there is a lock on the table during execution when it fails.

Probably the best thing to investigate further would be to add an exception handler that writes the exceptions to some table or file and see what error is raised e.g.

```
-- create a logging table
create table tmp_error_log (timestamp timestamp(0), Error_test varchar2(1000));

-- add a variable to your procedure declaration
v_sql        varchar2(1000);

-- add an exception handler just before the final end; statement on your procedure
exception
  when others then
     begin
        v_sql := 'insert into tmp_error_log values(''' || 
                 to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || ''', ''' || SQLERRM || ''')';
        dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
        execute immediate v_sql;
        commit;
     end;

-- see what you get in the table
select * from tmp_error_log;
```